# Verificar si input tiene esto, para repetir si es falso

Tags: python

```
nvefy = None
def nvefy():
    if Word.find(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0):
        nvefyT = True
    else:
        nvefyT = False
#Aqui empezar
Word = input("Insert words: ")
nvefy()
#Terminar y si encuentra numero repetir input
```

Alguna ayuda? Por que llevo 30 minutos buscando y no encuentro me como la cabeza.

Comment: ¿Ayuda? Usa un `while`.

Comment: ¿Puedes explicar con palabras qué es lo que pretendes? Leyendo el código no se entiende. Pero así de primeras veo un par de errores. La función no retorna nada, y supongo que debería retonar True o False. Y `Word.find()` no funciona como pretendes, pues solo sirve para decirte si una subcadena aparece dentro de otra, pero no le puedes especificar tantos parámetros como quieras (qe además deberían ser de tipo cadena)

Comment: Quizás lo que querías hacer es `if Word in "012345679"`, que daría `True` si `Word` es un dígito. Aunque para eso tienes ya `if Word.isdigit()` que es todavía mejor porque mira si **todos** los caracteres de `Word` son dígitos. Por otro lado `Word` sería mejor un parámetro y no una variable global.

Comment: Ese error no me di cuenta gracias, y realmente lo que quiero es que verifique si en input hay un numero ingresado, que si realmente hay un numero diga que hay error y que repita el input para esperar el resultado deseado por si se llega a entender. Solo quiero que se ingresen letras.

Comment: `if any(c.isdigit() for c in Word)` --> hay algún dígito entre los caracteres de Word